# Boost Version Numbers

Tags: boost

I don't understand why version numbers of the Boost Library are incremented only 1/100  (e.g. 1.33, 1.34, so on) even though major inclusions are made like huge libraries. Is there any strong motivation behind this?

Comment: Those are not decimal points, they are simply delimiters between the major, minor and revision numbers. It is just convention that we write them as x.y.z, it could have just as easily have been x-y-z or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the [Boost Faq](http://www.boost.org/users/faq.html):

> What do the Boost version numbers mean? The scheme is x.y.z, where x is incremented only for massive changes, such as a reorganization of many libraries, y is incremented whenever a new library is added, and z is incremented for maintenance releases. y and z are reset to 0 if the value to the left changes.

Comment: Certainly, the statement "y is incremented whenever a new library is added" is incorrect. For instance, 1.52.0, 1.45.0 didn't introduce any new library.

Comment: @IgorR. "whenever" vs "whenever and only whenever".